# Cascading Tree like Structure in ADF Dynamically?

Tags: user-interface, tree, master-detail, oracle-adf

I am need of representing a **Cascading Tree** Structure on UI of an ADF Application, but there is a catch,

> The depth of the Tree is unknown, i.e A Root Node has one or multiple nodes which in turn may have mutliple Child nodes.

My initial idea of dealing was, creating multiple Tables from which ADF BC Components are created with multiple VO's having Master - Detail kind of relation, but this works for 2 - 3 Tables or more may be, but I need to add **Dynamic Support** to it.

Any suggestion either Declartive or Programmatic Approach will be appreciated.

Thanking in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently ADF requires you to define rules for tree hierarchies, which limits the dynamic approach in that you i) need to have accessors defined on the ADF BC level between the views and ii) need to define rules based on these associations when configuring an ADF bound tree.

To achieve you requirement, you would build your own tree model based on the Trinidad ChildPropertyTreeModel

see: http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/model/ChildPropertyTreeModel.html

In this custom model you can then query ADF BC views (through the ADF binding layer or not) to build the dynamic tree structure you want